# gradle check version command report error

Tags: gradle

I just installed gradle on ubuntu 16.0, then run below command:

```
 gradle --version

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '11.0.14'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

It's very weird check version fail.

```
$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.14 2022-01-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.14+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.14+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16.04, mixed mode, sharing)
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
```

Comment: What is your available Java version?  Check your `JAVA_HOME`, as well as `java -version`.

Comment: java home and version looks good, updated above!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 16 dates back to 2015-2016 and reached end of life for standard support in [April 2021](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2016-April/000207.html).

Since you are running an outdated OS, my guess is that you also installed an older unsupported version of Gradle that is not compatible with later versions of Java.

Gradle 5 and above are compatible with Java 11, see the [Compatibility Matrix](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html) for details.

Additionally, the [Gradle Wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) is recommended instead of a local installation of Gradle.